# Upcoming events from Google Calendar in python

Tags: python, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have been working on google api with python and when I call the api for Google Calendar to get the list of events the response only has the events till the current day. Is there any way to get the upcoming events or the future events created in Google Calendars ??

This is my app.route in Flask

```
@app.route('/events',methods=['GET'])
def getEvents():
 eventsResult = service.events().list(calendarId='primary',maxResults = 18, singleEvents=True, orderBy = 'startTime').execute()
        print("HERE")
        if not eventsResult:
            return "NONE"
        events = eventsResult.get('items', [])
        print("##[EVENTS]##:\n",eventsResult)
        if not events:
            return jsonify({'status':'There are no events present'}),204
        count=1
        for event in events:
            # print("[SINGLE]:\n",event)
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            count = count + 1
        return jsonify(events),200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendars [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) returns all events, that includes events in the future dates. Check your filters, you might be asking to return only the events for today. You could also have more than 30 events so the others weren't being shown. I did a [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it) and it returned test events for February and March 2018:

```
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-02-01T09:30:00+08:00"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-02-01T10:30:00+08:00"
   },

    "start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-03-01T09:30:00+08:00"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-03-01T10:30:00+08:00"
   }
```

Give the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python) a try.

Comment: Okay ... Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than 18 events each day? If so up your max events 
This is what I have (in swift) and it returns events that are on days other than today

```
    let query = GTLRCalendarQuery_EventsList.query(withCalendarId: "primary")
    query.maxResults = 30
    query.timeMin = GTLRDateTime(date: Date())
    query.singleEvents = true
    query.orderBy = kGTLRCalendarOrderByStartTime

    service.executeQuery(
        query,
        delegate: self,
        didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
```

Comment: Okay :) i'll try this !